# How to identify the question fields when fetching survey information from the Lists web service?

Tags: web-services, survey-list

I am wanting to access survey information via the Lists web service and display the questions contained in the survey.

The result contains a large number of **Field** nodes some of which are the questions in the survey. The other fields contain other information such as author, last changed etc.

How can I pick out the questions? I had thought that all non-questions would be hidden but this is not the case.

Here is my code as it is at the moment. It returns about 16 items. The survey has 6 questions...

```
// read question definitions
string[] HandleTypes = new string[] { "Number", "DateTime", "Text", "Choice", "GridChoice", "Boolean" };
var query = from n in node.Descendants(ns+"Field")
            where (n.Attribute("Hidden") == null || n.Attribute("Hidden").Value.ToLower() == "true")
            && (n.Attribute("Type") != null && HandleTypes.Contains(n.Attribute("Type").Value))
            select new Question(n.Attribute("ID").Value)
            {
                Text = n.Attribute("DisplayName").Value,
                QuestionType = n.Attribute("Type").Value,
                Element = n
            };
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a global solution but it seems to work for me.

If I only take **Fields** which have a **Version** attribute then I just get my questions.

So my query looks like this:

```
var query = from n in node.Descendants(ns+"Field")
            where (n.Attribute("Hidden") == null || n.Attribute("Hidden").Value.ToLower() == "true")
            && (n.Attribute("Version") != null)
            select new Question(n.Attribute("ID").Value)
            {
                Text = n.Attribute("DisplayName").Value,
                QuestionType = n.Attribute("Type").Value,
                Element = n
            };
```

I'm going to try this to see how far it goes...

Comment: UPDATE - unfortunately, it is not good enough. There are some questions which do not have the version attribute :-(

Back to the drawing board....

Answer (score 0):

I do like this :

I noticed that for the fields which are not questions the attribute `SourceId = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"`. So I take the fields where `SourceId` doesn't contains `sharepoint`.

You also might want to take the fields Author, Created, Modified